# How to create an ordered map of tuples whose size is known after reading input in C++?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++20, ordered-map

I am trying to create an ordered map of tuples of ints whose size I know after reading input.

Something like:

```
map<tuple<int, int, ...>>
```

How do I do something like this in case I have **n** ints in the tuple?

Is it possible?

Comment: `std::tuple` required compile time known class template arguments. Much easier would be using a `std::map<std::vector<int>>`, where *n* (size of the vector) known at run time.

Comment: if the inputs are all same data type, you can use vector as the key, where the vector will contain the input.  For example: map<vector<int>, int> mp. 
If inputs are not same data type, you can keep structure as key

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I didn't know vectors culd be sued as keys.